# Setting Up a Keytab for a User Fails: "kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials"

Tags: linux, centos, authentication, kerberos, freeipa

I have a cluster of machines running CentOS 7.3. Kerberos, DNS, LDAP, etc. are in use in a unified manner via the use of FreeIPA 4.4.

I have a particular user that runs automated tests. Therefore, this users needs to be able to obtain a Ticket Granting Ticket without password entry. I have tried to accomplish this by creating a keytab and effectively "pre-entering" the password. However, I cannot **kinit** using the keytab, as shown below.

### GET THE KEY VERSION NUMBER (kvno) from the KDC

```
[root@kdc.example.com ~]# kadmin.local -q 'get_principal myuser@EXAMPLE.COM'
Authenticating as principal root/admin@EXAMPLE.COM with password.
Principal: myuser@EXAMPLE.COM
Expiration date: [never]
Last password change: Mon Jul 16 06:54:59 CDT 2018
Password expiration date: Tue Jul 23 06:54:59 CDT 2019
Maximum ticket life: 1 day 00:00:00
Maximum renewable life: 7 days 00:00:00
Last modified: Mon Jul 16 06:54:59 CDT 2018 (kadmind@EXAMPLE.COM)
Last successful authentication: Mon Jul 23 11:03:38 CDT 2018
Last failed authentication: Mon Jul 23 14:40:57 CDT 2018
Failed password attempts: 1
Number of keys: 2
Key: vno 3, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96:special
Key: vno 3, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96:special
MKey: vno 1
Attributes: REQUIRES_PRE_AUTH
Policy: [none]
```

### CREATE A KEYTAB, USING THE KVNO FROM ABOVE, ON THE CLIENT MACHINE

```
myuser@client-host.example.com$ cd /home/myuser
myuser@client-host.example.com$ mkdir .krb5
myuser@client-host.example.com$ chmod 700 .krb5
myuser@client-host.example.com$ cd /home/myuser/.krb5
myuser@client-host.example.com$ ktutil
ktutil:  addent -password -p myuser@EXAMPLE.COM -k 3 -e aes256-cts
Password for myuser@EXAMPLE.COM:
ktutil:  list
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    1                    myuser@EXAMPLE.COM
ktutil:  wkt myuser.keytab
ktutil:  exit
```

### LIST OUT THE KEYTAB WE JUST CREATED ON THE CLIENT MACHINE

```
myuser@client-host.example.com$ klist -kte myuser.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:myuser.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   1 07/23/2018 14:33:30 myuser@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

### ATTEMPT TO USE THE KEYTAB ON THE CLIENT MACHINE

```
myuser@client-host.example.com$ klist
klist: Credentials cache keyring 'persistent:4866486744:krb_ccache_rGHfj38' not found
myuser@client-host.example.com$ kinit myuser@EXAMPLE.COM -k -t /home/myuser/.krb5/myuser.keytab
kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials
```

Where am I going wrong in setting up the keytab for this user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure why using **ktutil** on the client did not work, but using **kadmin.local** on the server does:

```
kadmin.local
kadmin.local: ktadd -k myuser.keytab -norandkey myuser@EXAMPLE.com
kadmin.local: exit
```

Securely move this file to a secure directory on the client.

On the client, use this keytab file as follows:

```
kinit -k -t myuser.keytab myuser@EXAMPLE.COM
```